# Why react wai-aria is not in camelCase?

Tags: reactjs, accessibility, naming-conventions, wai-aria, camelcasing

From [react docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/accessibility.html)

> Note that all aria-* HTML attributes are fully supported in JSX.
> Whereas most DOM properties and attributes in React are camelCased,
> these attributes should be hyphen-cased (also known as kebab-case,
> lisp-case, etc) as they are in plain HTML:

AFAIK, every HTML attribute is renamed to camelCase in react.
Is there any reason to explain why `aria-*` is kept their original name?

Bonus, is there anyone know, should it be `<input autoFocus='autofocus'/>` or `<input autofocus='autofocus'/>`. The former looks correct because my editor does not throw any warning. But is it inconsistent between the attribute name and its value?

Should it also be `autocomplete` or `autoComplete`, while there is no hyphen between `auto` and `complete` in the original attribute name?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The React API Reference provides some information about this. At [DOM Elements](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html), it says:

> In React, all DOM properties and attributes (including event handlers) should be camelCased. For example, the HTML attribute `tabindex` corresponds to the attribute `tabIndex` in React. The exception is `aria-*` and `data-*` attributes, which should be lowercased. For example, you can keep `aria-label` as `aria-label`.

The section [All Supported HTML Attributes](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#all-supported-html-attributes) gives `autoComplete` and `autoFocus` as the expected names.

Now, this doesn't actually answer *why* the `aria-*` attributes remain lowercased, but at least it's a clear statement of how they are supposed to be used.

*Speculation:* Perhaps this has something to do with a change which took place between React versions 15 and 16. The blog post "[DOM Attributes in React 16](https://reactjs.org/blog/2017/09/08/dom-attributes-in-react-16.html)" explains that custom attributes are now allowed in React 16, which were previously stripped out.  It describes some concerns that an internal whitelist of attributes had become a maintenance burden, which needed to be simplified. Now arbitrary attributes can be included in JSX.  I don't know how this works internally, but I suppose the `aria-*` attributes play some part in the story of the internal whitelist.  For instance, WAI-ARIA 1.1 recently introduced several new `aria-*` attributes, and the WAI [Personalization Semantics Content Module](https://www.w3.org/TR/personalization-semantics-content-1.0/) working draft introduces a lot of `aui-*` attributes. Both of these would have needed to be whitelisted.